# How to call Bundle Arguments to not null

Tags: android, arguments, bundle, android-fragmentactivity

i make an argument but when i try open the application, it gave me error on line 124
how to call the argument so that can be show in the code?

here is my code, and what i've done

```
/**
 * A simple {@link Fragment} subclass.
 * Activities that contain this fragment must implement the
 * {@link LoginFragment.OnFragmentInteractionListener} interface
 * to handle interaction events.
 * Use the {@link LoginFragment#newInstance} factory method to
 * create an instance of this fragment.
 */
public class LoginFragment extends Fragment {

    ProgressDialog pDialog;
    Button btn_register, btn_login;
    EditText txt_username, txt_password;
    Intent intent;

    int success;
    ConnectivityManager conMgr;

    private String url = Server.URL + "login.php";

    private static final String TAG = LoginFragment.class.getSimpleName();

    private static final String TAG_SUCCESS = "success";
    private static final String TAG_MESSAGE = "message";

    public final static String TAG_USERNAME = "username";
    public final static String TAG_ID = "id";

    String tag_json_obj = "json_obj_req";

    SharedPreferences sharedpreferences;
    Boolean session = false;
    //String id, username;
    public static final String my_shared_preferences = "my_shared_preferences";
    public static final String session_status = "session_status";


    // TODO: Rename parameter arguments, choose names that match
    // the fragment initialization parameters, e.g. ARG_ITEM_NUMBER
    //private static final String ARG_PARAM1 = "param1";
    //private static final String ARG_PARAM2 = "param2";

    // TODO: Rename and change types of parameters
    private String id;
    private String username;

    private OnFragmentInteractionListener mListener;

    public LoginFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    /**
     * Use this factory method to create a new instance of
     * this fragment using the provided parameters.
     *
     * @param param1 Parameter 1.
     * @param param2 Parameter 2.
     * @return A new instance of fragment LoginFragment.
     */
    // TODO: Rename and change types and number of parameters
    public static LoginFragment newInstance(String id, String username) {
        LoginFragment fragment = new LoginFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putString(TAG_ID, id);
        args.putString(TAG_USERNAME, username);
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        conMgr = (ConnectivityManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        {
            if (conMgr.getActiveNetworkInfo() != null
                    && conMgr.getActiveNetworkInfo().isAvailable()
                    && conMgr.getActiveNetworkInfo().isConnected()) {
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(getContext(), "No Internet Connection",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }



        // Cek session login jika TRUE maka langsung buka MainActivity
        sharedpreferences = getActivity().getSharedPreferences(my_shared_preferences, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        session = sharedpreferences.getBoolean(session_status, false);
        id = sharedpreferences.getString(TAG_ID, id);
        username = sharedpreferences.getString(TAG_USERNAME, username);

        if (session) {
            id = getActivity().getIntent().getExtras().getString(TAG_ID);
            username = getActivity().getIntent().getExtras().getString(TAG_USERNAME);
            getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content, new UserFragment()).commit();
            //Intent intent = new Intent(getContext(), UserFragment.class);
            //intent.putExtra(TAG_ID, id);
            //intent.putExtra(TAG_USERNAME, username);
            //getActivity().finish();
            //startActivity(intent);
        }


        if (getArguments() != null) {
            id = getArguments().getString(TAG_ID);
            username = getArguments().getString(TAG_USERNAME);
        }

    }

    private void checkLogin(final String username, final String password) {
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());
        pDialog.setCancelable(false);
        pDialog.setMessage("Logging in ...");
        showDialog();

        StringRequest strReq = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, url, new Response.Listener<String>() {

            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Login Response: " + response.toString());
                hideDialog();

                try {
                    JSONObject jObj = new JSONObject(response);
                    success = jObj.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);

                    // Check for error node in json
                    if (success == 1) {
                        String username = jObj.getString(TAG_USERNAME);
                        String id = jObj.getString(TAG_ID);

                        Log.e("Successfully Login!", jObj.toString());

                        Toast.makeText(getContext(), jObj.getString(TAG_MESSAGE), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                        // menyimpan login ke session
                        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedpreferences.edit();
                        editor.putBoolean(session_status, true);
                        editor.putString(TAG_ID, id);
                        editor.putString(TAG_USERNAME, username);
                        editor.commit();

                        // Memanggil main activity
                        id = getActivity().getIntent().getExtras().getString(TAG_ID);
                        username = getActivity().getIntent().getExtras().getString(TAG_USERNAME);
                        getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content, new UserFragment()).commit();
                        //Intent intent = new Intent(getContext(), MainActivity.class);
                        //intent.putExtra(TAG_ID, id);
                        //intent.putExtra(TAG_USERNAME, username);
                        //getActivity().finish();
                        //startActivity(intent);
                    } else {
                        Toast.makeText(getContext(),
                                jObj.getString(TAG_MESSAGE), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                    }
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    // JSON error
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Login Error: " + error.getMessage());
                Toast.makeText(getContext(),
                        error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                hideDialog();

            }
        }) {

            @Override
            protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
                // Posting parameters to login url
                Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
                params.put("username", username);
                params.put("password", password);

                return params;
            }

        };

        // Adding request to request queue
        AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(strReq, tag_json_obj);
    }

    private void showDialog() {
        if (!pDialog.isShowing())
            pDialog.show();
    }

    private void hideDialog() {
        if (pDialog.isShowing())
            pDialog.dismiss();
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_login, container, false);

        btn_login = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.btn_login);
        btn_register = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.btn_register);
        txt_username = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.txt_username);
        txt_password = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.txt_password);
        btn_login.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                String username = txt_username.getText().toString();
                String password = txt_password.getText().toString();

                // mengecek kolom yang kosong
                if (username.trim().length() > 0 && password.trim().length() > 0) {
                    if (conMgr.getActiveNetworkInfo() != null
                            && conMgr.getActiveNetworkInfo().isAvailable()
                            && conMgr.getActiveNetworkInfo().isConnected()) {
                        checkLogin(username, password);
                    } else {
                        Toast.makeText(getContext() ,"No Internet Connection", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                } else {
                    // Prompt user to enter credentials
                    Toast.makeText(getContext() ,"Kolom tidak boleh kosong", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }
        });

        btn_register.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                //intent = new Intent(getContext(), RegisterFragment.class);
                //getActivity().finish();
                //startActivity(intent);
                getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content, new RegisterFragment()).commit();
            }
        });


        return view;
    }

    // TODO: Rename method, update argument and hook method into UI event
    public void onButtonPressed(String string) {
        if (mListener != null) {
            mListener.onLoginFragmentInteraction(string);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Context context) {
        super.onAttach(context);
        if (context instanceof OnFragmentInteractionListener) {
            mListener = (OnFragmentInteractionListener) context;
        } else {

        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onDetach() {
        super.onDetach();
        mListener = null;
    }

    /**
     * This interface must be implemented by activities that contain this
     * fragment to allow an interaction in this fragment to be communicated
     * to the activity and potentially other fragments contained in that
     * activity.
     * <p>
     * See the Android Training lesson <a href=
     * "http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html"
     * >Communicating with Other Fragments</a> for more information.
     */
    public interface OnFragmentInteractionListener {
        // TODO: Update argument type and name
        //void onFragmentInteraction(Uri uri);
        public void onLoginFragmentInteraction(String string);
    }

}
```

and i have error with this

```
    id = getActivity().getIntent().getExtras().getString(TAG_ID);
    username = getActivity().getIntent().getExtras().getString(TAG_USERNAME);
```

[here is the screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VGnSU.jpg)

how to call them from that fragment?
to show it's value

thanks for your help before

===========================================================================

ok the code already log in, now the problem is the code show null in user profile

here is the code

```
/**
 * A simple {@link Fragment} subclass.
 * Activities that contain this fragment must implement the
 * {@link UserFragment.OnFragmentInteractionListener} interface
 * to handle interaction events.
 * Use the {@link UserFragment#newInstance} factory method to
 * create an instance of this fragment.
 */
public class UserFragment extends Fragment {

    Button btn_logout;
    TextView txt_id, txt_username;
    //String id, username;
    SharedPreferences sharedpreferences;

    public static final String TAG_ID = "id";
    public static final String TAG_USERNAME = "username";

    // TODO: Rename parameter arguments, choose names that match
    // the fragment initialization parameters, e.g. ARG_ITEM_NUMBER
    //private static final String ARG_PARAM1 = "param1";
    //private static final String ARG_PARAM2 = "param2";

    // TODO: Rename and change types of parameters
    private String id;
    private String username;

    private OnFragmentInteractionListener mListener;

    public UserFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    /**
     * Use this factory method to create a new instance of
     * this fragment using the provided parameters.
     *
     * @param param1 Parameter 1.
     * @param param2 Parameter 2.
     * @return A new instance of fragment UserFragment.
     */
    // TODO: Rename and change types and number of parameters
    public static UserFragment newInstance(String id, String username) {
        UserFragment fragment = new UserFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putString(TAG_ID, id);
        args.putString(TAG_USERNAME, username);
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        sharedpreferences = getActivity().getSharedPreferences(LoginFragment.my_shared_preferences, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

        //id = getArguments().getString(TAG_ID);

        id = getActivity().getIntent().getStringExtra(TAG_ID);
        username = getActivity().getIntent().getStringExtra(TAG_USERNAME);

        if (getArguments() != null) {
            id = getArguments().getString(TAG_ID);
            username = getArguments().getString(TAG_USERNAME);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_user, container, false);
        TextView txt_id = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txt_id);
        TextView txt_username = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txt_username);
        txt_id.setText("ID : " + id);
        txt_username.setText("USERNAME : " + username);
        btn_logout = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.btn_logout);
        btn_logout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                // update login session ke FALSE dan mengosongkan nilai id dan username
                SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedpreferences.edit();
                editor.putBoolean(LoginFragment.session_status, false);
                editor.putString(TAG_ID, null);
                editor.putString(TAG_USERNAME, null);
                editor.commit();
                getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content, new LoginFragment()).commit();
                //Intent intent = new Intent(getContext(), LoginFragment.class);
                //getActivity().finish();
                //startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

        return view;
    }

    // TODO: Rename method, update argument and hook method into UI event
    public void onButtonPressed(String string) {
        if (mListener != null) {
            mListener.onUserFragmentInteraction(string);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Context context) {
        super.onAttach(context);
        if (context instanceof OnFragmentInteractionListener) {
            mListener = (OnFragmentInteractionListener) context;
        } else {
            //throw new RuntimeException(context.toString()
                    //+ " must implement OnFragmentInteractionListener");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onDetach() {
        super.onDetach();
        mListener = null;
    }

    /**
     * This interface must be implemented by activities that contain this
     * fragment to allow an interaction in this fragment to be communicated
     * to the activity and potentially other fragments contained in that
     * activity.
     * <p>
     * See the Android Training lesson <a href=
     * "http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html"
     * >Communicating with Other Fragments</a> for more information.
     */
    public interface OnFragmentInteractionListener {
        // TODO: Update argument type and name
        void onUserFragmentInteraction(String string);
    }
}
```

[null id and username](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x2EgY.jpg)

Comment: try to get using getArguments().getString(TAG_ID);

Answer (score 3):

if you are not sure the arguments has data inside, you can check if argumen has the value or not by

```
if (getArguments().containsKey(KEY_ID)) {
  id = getArguments().getString(KEY_ID);
}
```

and so on

Comment: i put this one                         if (getArguments().containsKey(TAG_ID)) {
                            id = getArguments().getString(TAG_ID);
                        }
                        if (getArguments().containsKey(TAG_USERNAME)) {
                            username = getArguments().getString(TAG_USERNAME);
                        }, error line "Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean android.os.Bundle.containsKey(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference"

Comment: there is different way to handle bundle between Activity and Fragment, for activity you can access by getIntent().getStringExtra(TAG_ID);  and for fragment you need to access the argument by getArguments().getString(TAG_ID); .  in this case you are using fragment and try to call activity method. please using getArguments instead of calling getActivity().getIntent ....

Comment: it's error to,         if (getArguments() != null) {
            id = getArguments().getString(TAG_ID);
            username = getArguments().getString(TAG_USERNAME);
        } and show null also

Comment: please see your LoginFragment, seems like you're not passing any data to UserFragment, instead of calling new UserFragment(), use your UserFragment.newInstance(id,username)

Answer (score 0):

`getActivity().getIntent().getExtras()` is returning null.

You might not have added anything in the `intent.putExtra()` and you are passing arguments may be. You can try using `getArguments.getString(TAG_ID);`

Comment: how to put this one? if i add id = getArguments.getString(TAG_ID); the getArguments in red color

Comment: Can you please tel me where you are passing data to UserFragment

Comment: Can u please explain the activity flow. I mean from where and when u will cal this fragments